# Avoid Visual Studio removing strings from resx file

Tags: visual-studio, resx

I'd like to manually add some additional strings to the resx file associated with a WinForms class. This works fine, and I can access these strings using a ResourceManager.

But as soon as I modify the form using Visual Studio designer, it rewrites the resx file and thus deletes my strings.

Is there any way to prevent Visual Studio designer from doing this?

(Please don't ask why I want to manually add some strings to the resx file. I just do.)

Comment: Yes, you'll lose your changes.  You just do.

Comment: Just to follow up on this, I just want to thank you for your comment Hans. Don't ask me why, I just do. 

What I ended up doing was writing a program that I run as a pre-build step that detects when Visual Studio designer has rewritten the resx file, and then I add my additional strings once again. Take that, Visual Studio designer!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of find a way to prevent Visual Studio designer from doing this. You should NOT put your non-GUI related resource in these files. Just because VS maintain these files.

For customized resource, icon, images, files, strings, you can add a resource file to your project, and a wrapper class will be generated whenever you modify the customized resource file.

You can select this file type in the Add File dialog(CTRL + SHIFT + A), it's category is "General". A companion file *.Designer.cs  will be generated(And added to your source code server if you have configured your VS in this way) automatically, and linked under the *.resx file.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Maybe I'll change my localization system to gather all localizations in a single .resx file someday, but for the moment I find it more convenient to have them in multiple .resx files, each associated with the class that the localization strings are used in. This works very well for the non-Forms classes. For the Forms classes I do have the problem of my program and Visual Studio designer having difficulty living in peace and harmony with each other, but my current workaround (see my comment to Hans) seems to work acceptably.